# Are there performance differences between DDR3 single-rank and dual-rank memory modules on Intel X58 with Core i7-960?

Tags: memory, dram, performance

I have an approximately 10 year old Intel X58 chipset with a Core i7-960 processor, and I would like to upgrade the system from 12 GB to 24 GB of memory to support computationally- and memory-intensive engineering simulations.  Both single-rank and dual-rank memory modules have equivalent costs.

One [artcile](https://www.oempcworld.com/support/singlevsdualram.html) claims, "Generally Single Rank Memory is faster than Dual Rank Memory, in layman’s terms when a computer accesses Single Rank Memory it only has to go around the track once, where are Dual Rank it would have to go around the track twice."

However, this [paper](https://user.eng.umd.edu/~blj/papers/memsys2018-dramsim.pdf) states, "Execution time is reduced 21% when moving from single-rank
DDR3 channels to dual-rank channels."  And, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgFXVhsK1ok) suggests there might be performance gains for some systems when going from single-rank to dual-rank.

I am not very familiar with the inner-workings of these electronics.  Is the performance gain when going from single-rank to dual-rank only realized on chipsets that support rank interleaving?

My BIOS does not have any options for rank interleaving that I can find.  Moreover, the [Intel Core i7-960 datasheet](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/core-i7-900-ee-and-desktop-processor-series-datasheet-vol-1.pdf) only mentions one output signal for selecting one rank as the target of the command and address.  [Datasheets for later generations](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/processors/core/core-technical-resources.html) such as the 4th Generation datasheet (volume 2) have registers for rank interleaving.  This leads me to believe that my chipset might not support rank interleaving, and perhaps, single-rank modules might have a slight performance advantage over dual-rank modules on my system.

So, would there be any performance differences between single-rank and dual-rank memory modules on the Intel X58 chipset with a Core i7-960 processor?

Are there any other things that should be considered when selecting between single-rank and dual-rank memory modules - such as reliability or power consumption?

Comment: How much it would cost to upgrade memory, and how much it consumes energy? For about 400 euros, you can get a CPU, motherboard and 32GB of memory, and that new one would be four times more powerful computer, and while cutting power consumption to half.

Comment: That's a fair point.  The cost to upgrade memory only is about $170 USD (or 155 Euros).  The question is intriguing to me, because the costs of SR and DR modules are the same.  Usually any kind of hardware selection has some kind of cost/performance trade space.  I just don't see it (or understand it, more likely) in the present case.